# How to compute shortest paths (by multiplying link weights) in a social network?

Tags: r, social-network

Basis: Adjacency matrix (633*633) containing the weighted direct links between each pair of actors (values are between 0 and 1).

Problem: I want to calculate the "shortest" path between each pair of actors by multiplying the values of the links on this path. I've already tried to use some functions of the `igraph` package (i.e., `distances()`, etc.).

Note: The "shortest" path does not necessarily represent the lowest possible number of links between two actors, but the highest possible product. Thus, a higher value stands for a higher relatedness.

Example: relatedness between a and b Actor a is linked to b (link value: 0.1). Actor b is linked to c (link value: 0.5). Actor a is linked to c (link value: 0.8).

In this case, the shortest path between a and b would be a --> c --> b and not the direct one, because 0.5*0.8 > 0.1!

Comment: Are you just asking for R code? If so, that would be off topic here. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Which forum would be suitable for that question?

Comment: For a concrete coding question with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536), you can ask on [SO]. Otherwise you could try the r-help listserv.

Answer (score 5):

As the logarithm is a monotone function, and because $\log(\prod_{i}a_i) = \sum_i \log(a_i)$ you can find the maximal product path by searching for the shortest path in the graph where you replaced the weights $a$ by $-\log(a)$ using the classic methods.

Comment: What do you mean by classic methods? I'm afraid I'm a beginner!

Comment: Any shortest path algorithm like Dijkstra etc. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)) as you are using R you might use the `shortest.path` method from the `igraph` package for example ([doc](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/shortest.paths)).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dijkstra algorithm just uses sums instead of the required products. Is there a way to modify that?

Comment: That's the whole point of applying the logarithm as indicated in my answer. You replace the weights so you can use an algorithms that works with the sum and obtain the same result. You obtain some path $\pi$ of transformed minimal sum length $d$ with the corresponding maximal product length $e^{-d}$.